# Picture-Sitemap for Google with TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

How can I use TYPO3 to create a sitemap for images that I can submit to Google?

This is not about the sitemap element from the menu content elements to expand images but actually a list of all published images of my site.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension to create a XML sitemap of used images. But it is not 9 LTS compatible yet.
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/tgm_copyright/

**UPDATE 12/2019**

The extension is now compatible with 9 LTS as well.

Comment: Yes, I know this app. But with TYPO3 and tx_seo this EXT might be obsolete.
At least I could not implement an egrnes update on TYPO3 9.5.

Comment: Thx Paul Beck i trotz the EXT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can have a list of all images in an easy way.

There are multiple ways to include images and all would need a side effect to mark the image for the picture sitemap.
Additionally you might use images which should not be listed as others used the same way should be listed. e.g. some background images might be mentionable, some are only styling like shades or structure.

In earlier days of TYPO3 you could build an index of all files in uploads as each used image was copied there, but now you only can index your original folders and may include unused images.

You might use a spider to scan all generated pages for the usage of images, but images could be included in multiple ways nowadays. Aside of the old `img` tags there are `picture` and more difficult CSS hiding images in background attributes to avoid easy copying.

Comment: Thank you Bernd, unfortunately not the answer I wanted to hear. ;-)

Does not every image I incorporate standard TYPO3 functions have a ref index, which only counts up when multiple inclusion in the Project drn counter?
So you could search through a DataProcessor all images from the filadmin and output the result of a fluid template?

Comment: I think this index is not reliable. every now and then a reference is missing or dead as a usage occurs without the core function which manages the references. and you still could miss images which get used in unusual ways like css, Also you can get references from records which are disabled.

Answer (score -1):

You can potentially do something using the data processors available since TYPO3 7.6 I believe.

e.g. using a combination of DatabaseQueryProcessor and FilesProcessor to fetch all content elements the user has access to:

```
lib.yourFluidTemplate = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.yourFluidTemplate {
    10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        pidInList = 1
        # all subpages as well
        recursive = 99
        as = contentElements

        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10 {
                # use field "assets"
                references.fieldName = assets
                as = files
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `lib.yourFluidTemplate` could be the template of your page or any fluid_styled_content template. As long is it uses `FLUIDTEMPLATE` content object.

After applying the typoscript above you should have a new variable in your fluid template named `contentElements` (the `as` variable defines what it's called), and each item should have a `files` key with the filenames.

This of course fetches all content elements starting from your root page (1 in this example) *regardless* if they have images or note, which might be excessive load.

Edit: you'd have to add one such configuration for each type of record, possibly multiple FilesProcessor configurations for each of them if it has multiple fields referencing images.